# PostgreSQL on Mountain Lion Server Autostart

Tags: macos, osx-server, postgresql

PostgreSQL now comes with Server on 10.8+.  However, postgres seems to require restarting often.  How can I keep postgres running without having to restart it so often?

Comment: What do you mean require restarting often? I've never had that problem.

Comment: If I don't hit the database for a while, postgres shuts down.  It works fine after I do a "sudo serveradmin start postgres" but I have to do that quite often.

Comment: I have 10.8.2 with server and I don't see PostgreSQL as an option. Where is it?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's the same in Mountain Lion Server, but perhaps this will help:

Disable automatic application termination in OS X 
http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20120726192014497

Comment: Please consider providing some important and applicable bits of information from the provided link; it's best practices to provide information from links in context.